# Where can i declare the charset of the model view? Zend FrameWork

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm new to zend framework and have been developing a application. During this developing I notice that the layout of the application reads UTF-8 but the model views of my modules don't.

I have done some research and some people where discussing that the model view class uses a different charset as standard and that I needed to config the model view before passing the content through it.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there are 2 places for the encoding:

Firs is in **layout.phtml** in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="...">
<head ...>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

And for MySQL in connection string to the DB. From **global.php**

```
'db'              => [
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'    => 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
],
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the time you took to write me a response, i really appreciate the effort.
First of all, I have UTF-8 encoded on the layout head (the same way as you showed above).
On the views of my Module, not only cant i see special characters from the content on my DB, as well as any text i wrote directly on the html file... that leads me believe that the problem doesnt consist on my db connection.
Im using doctrine for the db connection, is there any configuration there that im missing?

Comment: Update: I fixed half of the problem. My db config had everything config to "UTF-8" but my tables where using "latin_1". Now the content extracted from db has special characters but the text that i wrote directly on the html doesnt... 
From wierd to wierder

Comment: Update: I can see the special characters of the text, that i wrote directly on the html, if i use "utf8_encode()" function.. Its a very sloppy fix, so i am gonna keep this question open until i find a definitive solution.